# How do I upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10 now that 22.04 is out?

Tags: updates, 21.04

I have tried the normal way (sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, etc etc), but it keeps trying to go to 22.04, which obviously doesn't work because 21.04 isn't a supported upgrade path. I really don't want to have to reinstall my OS, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that freshly installing 22.04 might give you a cleaner system

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 has one *supported* & Quality-Assurance *tested* upgrade path; to the next release, which closed the moment Ubuntu 21.10 reached EOL on 14-July-2022.  You can *upgrade via re-install* for desktop systems, but it's intended for Ubuntu repository software only & desktop apps only (*system directories are erased thus some server app restoration maybe be required if using server setups*)

Comment: There hasn't been a supported upgrade path since your OS became EOL. Always release upgrade *before* the EOL date. Standard releases come out every 6 months. If you don't want to upgrade between 6-9 months, it's suggested to use a LTS release.

Comment: FYI:   if the bug report filed on a condition like this was you, the *upgrade via re-install* I mention is only tested with Ubuntu desktop installers; ie. `calamares` & `ubiquity`, and not server installer (`subiquity`) at least to my knowledge. Most server systems are managed & upgrades planned by owners/maintainers & thus its not an issue (*commonly using LTS too so they have years to do it instead of mere months*)